# Missing dll is not designed to be run on windows

Tags: windows-7

Guys, I've just created a program in C++ in Visual Studio. When I run exe file from my computer this program works as intended but if I try to run this program from another computer I'm getting message that msvcp100.dll is missing. Ok so I've found this dll and copied it into folder where my exe file is and I tried to run it and now I'm getting error: This ver of dll is not designed to run on Windows platform.
What's going on? How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need to have the VC++ redistributable package installed on the target machine.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a7b7a05e-6de6-4d3a-a423-37bf0912db84&displaylang=en

Also, I'm seeing that you can copy all the necessary .dll's to the program's folder on the target machine.

Comment: nope, realease mode was selected when building this project.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: most appreciated